# HP Desktop driver for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have an HP desktop computer, and I'm trying to install Windows 7, but it requires some drivers that I dont have. I've talked to some people that have installing windows on similar HP desktops, and they say that I need a Lenovo driver, not a HP driver.

The computer model is the "HP Pavilion 500-280eo". It was bought in Denmark.

I really hope you guys can help - It's been bugging me for 2 weeks now.

Comment: So you're saying that it can't install because there are no drivers for it?

Comment: @RsyaStudios It won't let me proceed the installation of Windows 7 without some driver.

Comment: @user375190: Windows 7 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath 64 bit

Comment: @user375190 Do you know for what device the driver you need? Usually windows installation will tell you which device it needs a driver for, like the HDD, or CPU

Answer (score 0):

from the first click at Internet search engine I found your drivers ,Your drivers at that link

[HP Pavilion 500-280eo Desktop PC support](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=7075108#N5075)

Or may be there is some thing else I don't understand , thank you

Comment: I've allready tried those drivers, but none of them works. As I wrote above, I talked to someone who downloaded Windows on simiar HP desktops, and he said that I need a Lenovo driver for some reason - I just don't know which.

Comment: Its impossible that HP make a wrong Drivers so the problem must be at windows , update to SP1 and download drivers for 64 bit not for 32 bit